# How to skip the alert "You've already purchased this but it hasn't been downloaded"

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I am testing my in app purchase application. While I purchase my consumable product second time with my user account in sandbox environment, it always show me a alert "You've already purchased this but it hasn't been downloaded. Tap OK to download it now.". Is there any way to skip the alert?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you got the solution... I am also getting same problem here.

Answer (score 15):

You should not see this alert if you are purchasing a consumable after already having done so. If you are, then you have never removed the transaction from the queue. You need to remove it before the store will let you purchase it again.

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not get rid of the problem for me.

Comment: That's right. Also ensure that your paymentQueue:updatedTransactions: is  being called after restarting simulator/device and check state of pending transactions. At some point you have to call finishTransaction to.

Answer (score 10):

Well, my solution after searching the web for several hours! Don't forget to add **transaction observer** for your IAP manager!!

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
```

> Your application should add an observer to the payment queue during application initialization. If there are no observers attached to the queue, the payment queue does not synchronize its list of pending transactions with the Apple App Store, because there is no observer to respond to updated transactions.
>
> If an application quits when transactions are still being processed, those transactions are not lost. The next time the application launches, the payment queue will resume processing the transactions. Your application should always expect to be notified of completed transactions.

Answer (score 6):

This is actually fairly complicated.  Apple has this message built into their transaction process, so if you let the user get to the point where they are attempting to repurchase a product they already own, they will see this message.

You can use

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

To restore any transactions they have previously purchased before they get to your buy screen. Run restoreCompletedTransactions before your store GUI loads, and then lock out the buy buttons of any content that is unlocked when a transaction is successfully completed.

Comment: Nope, restoreCompletedTransactions is of no use when using consumables.

Comment: Note that when calling `restoreCompletedTransaction` the password input screen will popup, and the user will probably not know why.

Comment: Note that if you do this the user will be required to enter their user name and password. Probably better left as a button the user can press from a settings menu.

Comment: This doesn't solve the "You've already purchased this but it hasn't been downloaded but we do not allow the developer to trigger a download again" error.

Answer (score 2):

This can also happen with perfectly valid code in an ad-hoc build if you're logged in with a non-sandbox ID, or the WRONG sandbox ID - like one from a different dev program than the cert the app was signed with. Like personal vs corporate for example.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have added this piece of code in the controller handling all the requests.

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:observer];
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem even though I did add the *transaction observer* and also did *remove the transaction* from the queue. I was able to fix it by cleaning up my provisioning profiles:

1. Go to Provisioning Portal and check if your distribution/developer provisioning profiles are still valid - renew them if necessary or at least refresh them by removing a device and adding it again.
2. Go to your organizer in XCode and delete all provisioning profiles, than hit refresh.
3. Delete your app **and all of your app provisioning profiles from your test device**
4. Sign out with your current test user from the appstore and sign in again later on when
   your in app purchase stuff will ask you to do so.
5. Clean, build and sign in with your test user when you buy an item in your app
6. Pray that it works for you too!

Comment: In the FWIW department, simply restarting my iPad Mini (running 7.0.4) also restored "normal" sandbox behaviour (without messing with the provisioning profiles - though I was going to try the steps above next!)

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed the problem after created a new account to use. I think Apple's system just gets backed up and messes up accounts for a while.

Good luck!